# Why my amp site with amp-facebook-comments not show?

Tags: facebook, amp-html

My website at: https://2top.xyz

My issues:

- AMP Facebook Comment plugin not show
- Test site: https://2top.xyz/dieu-khoan-cung-cap-va-su-dung-dich-vu-tai-website-2top.1574766128301
- I read at: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-facebook-comments/?format=websites and my code is:
- At header:

```html
<script async custom-element="amp-facebook-comments" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-facebook-comments-0.1.js"></script>
```

- At my body post:

```html
    <amp-facebook-comments width="486"
      height="657"
      layout="responsive"
      data-href="https://2top.xyz/dieu-khoan-cung-cap-va-su-dung-dich-vu-tai-website-2top.1574766128301">
    </amp-facebook-comments>
```

I don't know why this plugin not show, please help me! Thanks!

Note: this is my custom site I build with golang, upcloud vps and cloudflare cdn!

Comment: If you inspect your page data-href is incorrect`data-href="https://2top.xyz/https://2top.xyz/dieu-khoan-cung-cap-va-su-dung-dich-vu-tai-website-2top.1574766128301.1574766128301"`

Comment: Also, `data-href` refers to itself. Which feels wrong to me. You should have an external url.

Comment: @HastaTamang I fixed like you want, I'm also tested with external url but didn't work too. I checked warning log and I recieved: "The resource https://connect.facebook.net/vi/sdk.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally." I think this is cause of my problem. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issues myself. Because I didn't define width of parent `<div>` which contains the `<amp-facebook-comments>` component. So my final code is:

```html
<div class="comment" style="width:100%">
 <amp-facebook-comments
   width="480"
   height="720"
   layout="responsive"
   data-href="https://2top.xyz/dieu-khoan-cung-cap-va-su-dung-dich-vu-tai-website-2top.1574766128301">
 </amp-facebook-comments>
</div>
```

And it's working now!